# Print HTML with IF Statement

Tags: html, asp-classic

I'm traducing a small PHP script to clasic ASP, but I don't know how can I do this in ASP

```
<?php if ($anyCondition == true): ?>
<p>This is a HTML paragraph, it will be printed if $anyCondition will be true</p>
<?php else: ?>
<p>This is another HTML paragraph, it will be printed if $anyCondition will be false</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is it possible? Are there similar alternatives?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: There are any number of tutorials on the web for this.

Comment: ...must...resist...correcting...English...grammar... [Hint: the repeated "will be" is giving me conniptions, because trying to figure out the temporal logic of it just sends me into loop-de-loops.]

Comment: thanks @Martha i'm just learning english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while... If I can remember, it should be this:

```
<% If anyCondition = True Then %>

<p>This is a HTML paragraph, it will be printed if <%=anyCondition%> will be true</p>

<% Else %>

<p>This is another HTML paragraph, it will be printed if <%=anyCondition%> will be false</p>

<% End If %>
```

Comment: Beat me by 10 seconds!

Comment: You don't need to say `= True` - the `anyCondition` implies a True / False in this case, so just `If anyCondition Then` would suffice (keeps it easy to read).

Comment: Indeed. I just left it in order he could be aware "==" means "="  in ASP.